# ElasticSearch DSL: query on custom tags too

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new to ES, but already have a basic query that I need to extend.
The query is currently doing a search based on keywords and also on geo-distance.

Now, I have added a custom tag into my index, and I wish to take it into account too.
I wish to filter and score my results based on the imageTags (tag + score)!

PS: I have seen other similar posts, but I can't figure out how to adapt my query (none of my attempts work).

Here is my query:

```
GET /posts_index/_search
{
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "from":0,
    "size":10,
    "_source": [
        "id",
        "tags",
        "taxonomies",
        "storesNames",
        "geoLocations",
        "storesIds",
        "imageUri"
    ],
    
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "distance_feature": {
                                "field": "geoLocations",
                                "pivot": "10km",
                                "origin": [
                                    -71.3,
                                    41.15
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "distance_feature": {
                                "field": "creationTime",
                                "pivot": "14d",
                                "origin": "now"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "fields": [
                                    "tags^3",
                                    "taxonomies^5"
                                ],
                                "query": "",
                                "fuzziness": "auto"
                            }
                        },
                    ]
            
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "Math.sqrt(doc['commentsCount'].value)"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "Math.log(2 + doc['likesCount'].value)"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "Math.log(2 + doc['viewsCount'].value)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "avg"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of my attempts to modify it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "imageTags",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
              "query": {
                  "match": {
                      "imageTags.tag.keyword": "tripod"
                  }
              },
              "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "imageTags.score",
                  "factor": 1,
                  "missing": 0
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }             
}
```

By example, here is and example of the index:

```
{
  "id": "4a9afd93-62bc-e8b2-29b4-39f5b073336d",
  "tags": [
    "fashion",
    "mode",
    "summer"
  ],
  "imageTags": [
    {
      "score": 0.95150965,
      "tag": "four-poster"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.014835004,
      "tag": "window"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.014835004,
      "tag": "shade"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.009375425,
      "tag": "sliding"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.009375425,
      "tag": "door"
    }
  ],
  "taxonomies": [],
  "categories": [],
  "qualityScore": 0.0,
  "geoLocations": [
    {
      "lat": 50.4651156,
      "lon": 4.865208
    }
  ],
  "storesIds": [
    "ba9b3f59-50aa-8774-11a7-39f5ad58ae1a"
  ],
  "storesNames": [
    "Zara Namur"
  ],
  "creationTime": "2020-06-10T12:48:30.5710000Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-06-10T12:48:30.5710000Z",
  "imageUri": "https://localhost:44359/cdn/e_76372856-f7a0-49cc-d3d9-39f5ad58ad6d/653d147084637b2af68b39f5b0733359.jpg",
  "description": "",
  "likesCount": 0,
  "viewsCount": 0,
  "commentsCount": 0,
  "ImageTags": [
    {
      "score": 0.95150965,
      "tag": "four-poster"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.014835004,
      "tag": "window"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.014835004,
      "tag": "shade"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.009375425,
      "tag": "sliding"
    },
    {
      "score": 0.009375425,
      "tag": "door"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I wish to index on the imageTags.tag`?

Comment: Oups, sorry... wrong vocabulary! I have fixed. I mean that I wish to search/filter on the "ImageTags", and the "ImageTags.score" will play a role in the final score.